# Hibernate: Envers does not work with derived classes with no member fields

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-envers, sprint

Given the following base class...

```
...
import org.hibernate.envers.Audited;

@Audited
@Entity
@Table(
    name = "account",
    indexes = {
      @Index(name = "account_currency_id_idx", columnList = "currency_id")
    })
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "account_type")
public class Account {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  @Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
  @NotNull
  private Long id;

  @Audited
  @LastModifiedDate
  @Column(name = "last_modified_date_time")
  @Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
  private LocalDateTime lastModifiedDateTime;

  @Audited
  @LastModifiedBy
  @Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "last_modified_by_user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
  @Audited(targetAuditMode = NOT_AUDITED)
  private User lastModifiedByUser;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "currency_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
  @ApiFieldMappingProperty("currencyId")
  @Audited(targetAuditMode = NOT_AUDITED)
  private Currency currency;

  @NotNull
  @Column(name = "open_date", nullable = false)
  private LocalDate openDate;

  @Column(name = "close_date")
  private LocalDate closeDate;

  ...
}
```

... I defined two derived classes with no member fields but with a discriminator value that let me differentiate account types automatically. Here's the first derived class...

```
...
@Entity(name = "domestic_account")
@DiscriminatorValue("DOMESTIC")
public DomesticAccount extends Account {
}
```

... and here's the second one:

```
@Entity(name = "offshore_account")
@DiscriminatorValue("OFFSHORE")
public OffshoreAccount extends Account {
}
```

In the code I never use class `Account` directly; instead, I always instantiate (and save) either a `DomesticAccount` or a `OffshoreAccount`.

The problem is that even if I enabled auditing with `@Audited`, changes get never logged and table `ACCOUNT_AUD` remains empty.

Am I missing something? Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Looks fine to me. I guess the `@Audited` annotation is from Hibernate and not the one from Spring data, right? Anyway, if you think this is a bug, please create an issue in the issue tracker(https://hibernate.atlassian.net) with a test case(https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-test-case-templates/blob/master/orm/hibernate-orm-5/src/test/java/org/hibernate/bugs/JPAUnitTestCase.java) that reproduces the issue.

Comment: Thank you very much for your support... adding @Audited to the derived classes (even if they don't have any member fields) fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, annotating the derived classes with `@Audited` fixed the issue:

```
...
import org.hibernate.envers.Audited;

@Audited
@Entity(name = "domestic_account")
@DiscriminatorValue("DOMESTIC")
public DomesticAccount extends Account {
}
```

Also many thanks to [Christian Beikov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/412446/christian-beikov) for his support.